# How to insert jstree checkbox value into database

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, checkbox, jstree

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    //fill data to tree  with AJAX call
    $('#tree-container').jstree({
 'plugins': ["wholerow", "checkbox"],
        'core' : {
            'data' : {
                "url" : "response.php",
                "dataType" : "json" // needed only if you do not supply JSON headers
            }
        }
    })
});
</script>


 <div id="tree-container"></div>
```

```html
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "defectsystem";

$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname) or die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `treeview_items` ";
$res = mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die("database error:". mysqli_error($conn));
 //iterate on results row and create new index array of data
 while( $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res) ) { 
  $data[] = $row;
 }
 $itemsByReference = array();

// Build array of item references:
foreach($data as $key => &$item) {
   $itemsByReference[$item['id']] = &$item;
   // Children array:
   $itemsByReference[$item['id']]['children'] = array();
   // Empty data class (so that json_encode adds "data: {}" ) 
   $itemsByReference[$item['id']]['data'] = new StdClass();
}

// Set items as children of the relevant parent item.
foreach($data as $key => &$item)
   if($item['parent_id'] && isset($itemsByReference[$item['parent_id']]))
      $itemsByReference [$item['parent_id']]['children'][] = &$item;

// Remove items that were added to parents elsewhere:
foreach($data as $key => &$item) {
   if($item['parent_id'] && isset($itemsByReference[$item['parent_id']]))
      unset($data[$key]);
}
// Encode:
echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

I had successfully create a jstree with checkbox. However, how I can insert the checkbox value into the database when I click it and submit.

Thankss if anyone could help me!! If any question can ask me below comment.

Answer (score 1):

Try some thing like this:

```
var array = [];
// create an array

$.each($("input[name='user_permission']:checked"), function(){
    permissions.push($(this).val());
});
// Iterate over each checkbox which is checked and push its value in the array variable.
```

Ex:

```
......
var permissions = [];
$.each($("input[name='user_permission']:checked"), function(){
    permissions.push($(this).val());
});

$.ajax({
    url         : 'add_permission.php',
    method      : 'post',
    data       :
    {
        permissions : JSON.stringify(permissions)
    }
    ....
});
// After complete iteration you will get the value of each checked checkbox.
```

Now insert it in database using ajax call

Comment: Ya, I had find a lot of similar coding like this.

Comment: I am using it in my project and it working like a charm

Comment: For example, 

function submitMe() {
 var checked_ids = [];
 $('#your-tree-id').jstree('get_checked',null,true).each(function(){
  checked_ids.push(this.id);
 });
 //setting to hidden field
 document.getElementById('jsfields').value = checked_ids.join(",");
}
</script>

Comment: I see, can u explain more detail?

Comment: Thanks! One more question. I l had three level in my jstree. For example, Company is level 1, project is level 2, phase is level 3. I want insert it into a table which contain 3 column. How I can do that?